# Standalone light-weight javascript router for update content

Tags: javascript

I have simple web page with jquery and 4 page. Header, footer and all pages is static. I am looking the light-weight standalone `javascript` router for router of contents. My goal is update content without reloading page like `angular` `ui.router` do. Main requirements is change url when user click on link, and route to page content when user come in directly via url e.g. `example.com/page1`

- index.html
- page1.html
- page2.html
- page3.html

Comment: Shopping questions are off-topic for Stackoverflow. I fail to see why you need JavaScript though. You have static pages. Just link to them with plain HTML links.

Comment: My goal is implement it not reloading page.

Comment: Do you have to use native javascript ? Are you allowed to use frameworks such as Angular, Knockout, backbone?

Comment: Yes I use native javascript, also I use Jquery, but not use frameworks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at these pages:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/popstate
- https://css-tricks.com/using-the-html5-history-api/
- http://html5doctor.com/history-api/

They are all about the html5 history API. With that, you can modify for example the URL without reloading. 
You can check the URL for changes, and depending on that load / display a view.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very straightforward example of history-based routing https://github.com/yevt/simplistic-spa-router/blob/master/app.js.

You can clone this repo, it's working example. To play with that you will need static web-server. I used this one while testing: https://github.com/indexzero/http-server.

Comment: very simple yet good insttruactions rest is ones own creativity of course

Answer (score 0):

It's called SPA (Single Page Application). You can use AngularJS with [ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) to handle this.

Take a look at this [tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating).

Comment: I am looking only routing functionality, because angular 1.5.3 is 155,9 kb size, to big for me in this situation when my goal is only change html content  .